# While i tried to convert this to json using *json.loads* it throws this error,i need to remove the additional char after the curly and convert to json

Tags: json, python-3.x, encryption, dictionary-comprehension

```
"{
  "order_currncy": "INR",
  "order_ship_country": "India",
  "order_ship_email": "",
  "order_notes": "",
  "order_status": "Successful",
  "order_capt_amt": 0.0,
  "order_delivery_details": "",
  "order_fee_flat": 0.0,
  "order_discount": 0.0,
  "order_TDS": 0.0,
  "error_desc": "",
  "status": 0,
  "error_code": ""
}\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b"
```

**in decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 1462 (char 1461)**

Comment: Get rid of the trailing `\x0b...\x0b`. That looks like PKCS#7 padding bytes. Did you forget the unpadding after your decryption?

Comment: Can you please share any examples?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```py
import json

j = """{
  "order_currncy": "INR",
  "order_ship_country": "India",
  "order_ship_email": "",
  "order_notes": "",
  "order_status": "Successful",
  "order_capt_amt": 0.0,
  "order_delivery_details": "",
  "order_fee_flat": 0.0,
  "order_discount": 0.0,
  "order_TDS": 0.0,
  "error_desc": "",
  "status": 0,
  "error_code": ""
}"""

x = json.loads(j)
print(x)
```

result is a dict `x`